# How do I dinamically change the action atribute of an HTML form with php?

Tags: php, html, string, forms, action

I'm working in an online experiment where I need a subject to listen and rate some audios. Each audio will be evaluated in a different HTML form, and I want to send the results via php email().

I'm having some difficulties because ideally these audios should be presented in a different listening order for each subject. to this purpose I've also programmed a simple php script that randomizes the playing order. This is stored in a php array: *$playingOrderArray*, from where I shift and obtain one value after another. then, I add the server route as:

```
$nextPage = "test_".array_shift($playingOrderArray).".php";
```

I want to input this string into the action attribute from a form HTML tag:

```
<form action = <nextPage>.php method="post">
```

But I'm having a hard time finding a way to pass the string to select the direction page.
I should add that the whole code is in one file with .php extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action = "<?php echo $nextPage ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Php like this:

```
<form action = "<?php echo $pageUrl ?>" method="post">
```

Or you can use this line inside a JS function:

```
   $('#formId').attr('action', pageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
<form action = "<?= $pageUrl; ?>" method="post">
```